# Foreach image uploaded in a Node Content : get the url

Tags: php, twig, drupal-8

I'm beginning with Drupal 8 and I want to get the url of the photos in the content I create to display them.

The context is: a photograph upload pictures for a customer. This customer can see it on a page. To get this data in common I created a content for my shooting with an id.
What i did is:

`$photos = $shooting->field_shooting_photos->target_id;`
This allow me to get the id of every pictures uploaded. Now I want to do a foreach on $photos in my .module that will return every url in an array.
Then I will use this array in my Twig and do a foreach on it too to return every photos.
I just can't figure out how to do, I think I will have to use something like that

`$path = $photo_id->getFileUri();`
but I can't figure out the syntax to get it into an array.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a fid, you need to load the file.

```php
use \Drupal\file\Entity\File;

$fid = 123; // Your fid   
$file = File::load($fid);
```

From there, you can use the [getFileUri](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Entity%21File.php/function/File%3A%3AgetFileUri/8.2.x) method to get the URI. If you want to get the complete URL, you can use the [file_create_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/8.2.x) function.

```php
$uri = $file->getFileUri();
// You get : public://directory/file.jpg
$url = file_create_url($uri);
// You get : http://mywebsite.com/sites/default/files/directory/file.jpg
```